# How can I earn a rating of 11/10 on Game Dev Tycoon?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I saw this screenshot, which shows someone earning an 11/10 for their game.

What steps do I need to take to earn this?

[image: 11/10]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's rather based on luck.

First off, you should know [that guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=216784744) telling a lot about possible matches of topic, genre, audience and system.

- You should have a good team.
- Use your boosts at the right time.
- Develop a sequel of a really successful game (10 rating) to increase your chance of having a 11/10 score.
- Have luck.

You should also read this [wiki article](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Development_Based_on_Experience/1.4.3) which is really insightful about the game. You can't force a 11/10, you must be patient, and do the right things at the right time to increase your luck.